# Recharts - Is there any way to hide one part of stroke on a Bar

Tags: d3.js, recharts

Can't seem to find any way of doing this.

Radius accepts an array, but stroke doesn't.
Does that mean there's no way of specifying individual borders?

Really appreciate any help!

Here is the plot. I want to the remove the stroke that is on the left side.
[image]